# Count numbers in range that have consecutive digits in ascending order in its decimal representation

Tags: python, algorithm

If an integer has at least three consecutive digits in ascending order in its decimal representation then it is a special number.

The three digits in consecutive order must be greater than zero.

For example: `123`, `45123`, `245789`, `123456789`, `12345` are `special` numbers and `012` , `1012`, `1245` are `not special` numbers.

I have to count the number of special numbers that exist in the range between given `S` to `E`. (`1 <= S,E <= 10^18`)

A brute force approach can iterate over all numbers and check the digits for each one of them. But I am looking for an approach that skips some numbers and has a better time complexity than a brute force approach.

Do any such solution(s) exists?

Comment: Does the number need to ONLY have consecutive digits ? if not, you can simply created all combinations of the 9 patterns (123, 234, 345,... 789) with other digits as string constraining length and value to the range.  That should be much faster than brute force and even faster if you only aim to count how many there are

Comment: I am quite sure you can set up up a pattern for these using what Alain T. pointed out. Shift the blocks. 123, 234, 345,... 789, 1230, 1231, 1232, 1234, ... 2340. It will get more funny the more digits you have  12300 12301, then there are also patterns like 12340, 12345 with two or more sequences.

Comment: So, yes, there are 7 3 digit patterns 123, 234, ..., 789.  Then for numbers up to 10^18 there are approximately 10^15 digit combinations, and 16 different places you can insert each of the 7 3 digit patterns, for ~ 7 * 16 * 10^15 "special" numbers.  Does this sound like a big number ?

Comment: Another thing that you could try to write all numbers in a matrix, one digit per cell. Then you could use something like numpy's cumsum along each row followed by np.diff and probably something else. Then you should be able to identify the numbers. Would be vectorized, but consume lots of memory for the large numbers, probably do in chunks.

Comment: *"I have to find all special numbers .... Brute force approach can make it count..."*: do you need to *find* or *count*?

Comment: @trincot I just want count

Answer (score 0):

> Do any such solution(s) exists?

Such solutions certainly exist, and it's possible to count the special numbers between `S` and `E` effectively even if `S` and `E` are much larger than `10**18`. For example, we'll see below that there are exactly `26854019828391474979539976989876500770006474049724` special numbers smaller than `10**50`, so approximately one quarter of all 50-digit numbers are special.

I'll outline the idea for the solution, and then give some code in Python.

First the easy part: it's enough to be able to count special numbers in `range(n)` for any nonnegative integer `n`. That is, we just need a function:

```
def count_special_below(n: int) -> int:
    """
    Return count of special numbers m satisfying 0 <= m < n.
    """
    # See below for implementation
```

Given `count_special_below` (which we'll define properly later), we can easily find the count of special numbers in any given range with the following function:

```
def count_special_between(start: int, end: int) -> int:
    """
    Return count of special numbers m satisfying start <= m <= end.
    """
    return count_special_below(end + 1) - count_special_below(start)
```

### The idea

We'll divide the nonnegative integers into several classes. One of those classes will be the special numbers; the rest will be non-special numbers of various forms. The division is done in such a way that we know how the class of any given integer changes when we add a given digit.

Specifically, we define sixteen mutually-exclusive classes, numbered from 0 through 15, as follows:

- class 15 contains all special numbers
- class 14 contains all non-special numbers that end in the digits "78"
- class 13 contains all non-special numbers that end in the digits "67"
- class 12 contains all non-special numbers that end in the digits "56"
- class 11 contains all non-special numbers that end in the digits "45"
- class 10 contains all non-special numbers that end in the digits "34"
- class 9 contains all non-special numbers that end in the digits "23"
- class 8 contains all non-special numbers that end in the digits "12"
- class 7 contains all non-special numbers that end in "7", but not "67"
- class 6 contains all non-special numbers that end in "6", but not "56"
- class 5 contains all non-special numbers that end in "5", but not "45"
- class 4 contains all non-special numbers that end in "4", but not "34"
- class 3 contains all non-special numbers that end in "3", but not "23"
- class 2 contains all non-special numbers that end in "2", but not "12"
- class 1 contains all non-special numbers that end in "1"
- class 0 contains all non-special numbers that end in "8", "9" or "0", but not in "78"

The point of these classes is that if `n = 10*q = r` for some `q` and `r`, then we can compute the class of `n` knowing only the *class* of `q` and the value of `r`: we don't need to know `q` itself.

For example, if `q` is in class `9` and `r = 4`, then `n = 10*q + r` is in class 15: it's special. Whereas if `q` is in class `9` and `r = 5`, then `n` is in class `5`, and if `q` is in class `9` and `r = 0`, then `n` is in class `0`.

We can go through all 160 combinations of (class, digit) to compute the transitions, and then record those transitions in a simple list of lists.

Now we can scale this up: suppose again that `n = 10*q + r`, and that we've already computed (for example recursively) the number of integers in `range(q)` belonging to each of the 16 classes. Then we can use the transition matrix to compute the number of integers in `range(n)` belonging to each of the 16 classes.

For example, if `n = 135457`, `q = 13545` and `r = 7`, then the number of values of class `9` in `range(q)` turns out to be `121`. Each of those `121` values contributes exactly one special number to `range(135457)`, by appending a `4`. There are also `135` values of class `8`, which likewise each contribute to one special number in `range(135457)`. By adding the contributions, and also taking care to account for the range `range(135450, 135457)`, we get the total counts for each of the classes in `range(135457)`.

### The Python code

Here's the code, in iterative form. It would be more natural to express it recursively than iteratively, but then we'd run into Python's recursion limit for really large start and end values (for example having thousands of digits).

First the transition matrix: this is a list of lists, with rows corresponding to the sixteen classes, and columns corresponding to the digits. If `q` has class `c`, then `10*q + r` has class `transitions[c][r]`.

```
transitions = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 6, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 13, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 15, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 15, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15, 6, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 15, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 15],
    [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15],
]
```

And now the full `count_special_below` function:

```
def count_special_below(n: int) -> int:
    """
    Return count of special numbers m satisfying 0 <= m < n.
    """
    n_counts, n_cls = [0] * 16, 0
    for digit in map(int, str(n)):
        m_counts = [0] * 16
        for tc, count in zip(transitions, n_counts):
            for tcs in tc:
                m_counts[tcs] += count
        for t in transitions[n_cls][:digit]:
            m_counts[t] += 1
        n_counts, n_cls = m_counts, transitions[n_cls][digit]

    return n_counts[15]
```

### Testing the solution

For testing purposes, let's also define a brute force version:

```
def is_special(n: int) -> bool:
    """
    Return True if n is special, else False.
    """
    s = str(n)
    return any(
        substr in s
        for substr in ["123", "234", "345", "456", "567", "678", "789"]
    )

def count_special_between_brute(start: int, end: int) -> int:
    """
    Return count of special numbers m satisfying start <= m <= end.
    """
    return sum(is_special(n) for n in range(start, end + 1))
```

Some tests, with small numbers:

```
>>> count_special_between(125, 289901)
7593
>>> count_special_between_brute(125, 289901)
7593
>>> count_special_between(0, 10**7)
324691
>>> count_special_between_brute(0, 10**7)
324691
```

But our new function also performs happily with much larger numbers:

```
>>> count_special_between(0, 10**50)
26854019828391474979539976989876500770006474049724
```

Even counting special numbers below `10**10000` takes only a second or two on my machine, but since the answer has exactly `10000` digits (not surprisingly, since "most" large numbers will be special), I won't include it here.

### Connections with regular expressions

It's well known that matching by a regular expression (in the strict mathematical sense) can be implemented by a [deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (DFA). If we think of "special number" as applying to digit strings rather than integers, we can write a simple regular expression that matches special numbers:

```
special = "[0-9]*(123|234|345|456|567|678|789)[0-9]*"
```

This regular expression can be compiled to a DFA having exactly sixteen states, corresponding to the sixteen classes described above. In fact, if we use the Python package [`greenery`](https://github.com/qntm/greenery) (which I only just discovered), we can see that compilation explicitly. (I've edited whitespace into the session below to make it more readable, but it's otherwise unchanged.)

```
>>> from greenery.lego import parse
>>> p = parse("[0-9]*(123|234|345|456|567|678|789)[0-9]*")
>>> p.to_fsm()
fsm(
    alphabet = {'2', '1', '7', anything_else, '0', '4', '8', '3', '5', '6', '9'},
    states = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
    initial = 0,
    finals = {15}, map = {
        0: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        1: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 8, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        2: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 9, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        3: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 10, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        4: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 11, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        5: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 12, '7': 7, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        6: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 13, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        7: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 14, '9': 0},
        8: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 15, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        9: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 15, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        10: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 15, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        11: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 15, '7': 7, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        12: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 15, '8': 0, '9': 0},
        13: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 15, '9': 0},
        14: {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 0, '9': 15},
        15: {'0': 15, '1': 15, '2': 15, '3': 15, '4': 15, '5': 15, '6': 15, '7': 15, '8': 15, '9': 15}})
```

An inspection will verify that in fact the `map` above exactly corresponds to the transition table we created earlier.